# How to get a list of user defined data types on Sybase ASE?

Tags: sql, sap-ase, user-defined-types

I use the following query to get the list of user defined data types (UDDTs):

```
SELECT USER_NAME(S.uid) as owner, S.name as Name, T.name as datatypename, 
         OBJECT_NAME(S.domain), OBJECT_NAME(S.tdefault) 
FROM systypes S,systypes T 
WHERE S.type=T.type AND T.usertype<100 AND T.usertype NOT IN(18,24,25,80) AND S.usertype>100  
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

On Sybase 12.5, it used to return to return a single row per UDDT.  Now with Sybase 15.x, it returns 2 rows:

```
owner   Name    datatypename 
'dbo'  'auid'  'varchar'
'dbo'  'auid'  'longsysname'
```

The datatype of the UDDT is actually `varchar`.  I am not sure where the `longsysname` is coming from.
What is the correct way to return the list of UDDTs that works in both 12.5.x and 15.x ASE databases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code:

```
select s1.name, 
        (select name 
         from systypes s2 
         where s2.usertype=(
                            select min( s3.usertype) 
                            from systypes s3 
                            where  s3.hierarchy=s1.hierarchy)
        ) base_type,  USER_NAME(s1.uid) as owner
    from systypes s1
    WHERE s1.usertype>100
```